# Weird problem with PHP Breadcrumb Script

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I'm using Mick Sears' php breadcrumb script - found here:
http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_breadcrumbs-118.html

I've used this script several times with no problems.  But with this one site I'm having the weirdest problem...  Home page - fine.  Level 1 page - fine.  But every time I move to a level2 page, the correct level1 crumb is replaced by "Help".  The link on the crumb is the correct one for the help page.  This happens even if I clear all browser caches and don't go to the Help section of the site at all.

The site is http://www.fastexas.org.  The script is there, but I gave the breadcrumb div display:none; until I can figure this out.

This script seems to have been around awhile and I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this problem.

Comment: Do you have any of the surrounding code that we might be able to look at?  It's rather difficult to debug something without code.

Answer (score 0):

The Breadcrumb Script:

```
<?php
class Breadcrumb{
var $output;
var $crumbs = array();
var $location;
function Breadcrumb(){  
  if ($_SESSION['breadcrumb'] != null){
     $this->crumbs = $_SESSION['breadcrumb'];}  } 
 function add($label, $url, $level){
  $crumb = array();
  $crumb['label'] = $label;
  $crumb['url'] = $url;
  if ($crumb['label'] != null && $crumb['url'] != null && isset($level)){            
     while(count($this->crumbs) > $level){ 
        array_pop($this->crumbs); }
     if (!isset($this->crumbs[0]) && $level > 0){  
 $this->crumbs[0]['url'] = "/index.php";
        $this->crumbs[0]['label'] = "Home";}
     $this->crumbs[$level] = $crumb;}

    $_SESSION['breadcrumb'] = $this->crumbs; 
    $this->crumbs[$level]['url'] = null;}
function output(){
  echo "<ul>"; 
  foreach ($this->crumbs as $crumb){ 
if ($crumb['url'] != null){
echo "<li>  <a href='".$crumb['url']."' title='".$crumb['label']."'>".$crumb['label']."</a></li> ";} else {
echo "<li class='last'>".$crumb['label']."</li> ";}}
echo "</ul>";}}
?>
```

Each page begins with something like:

```
 <?php session_start(); 
 $level= '1'; 
 $label= 'Honors Circle'; 
 $url= '/honors/'; include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/Breadcrumb.php"); 
 $trail = new Breadcrumb(); 
 $trail->add($label, $url, $level); ?>
```

or

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$level= '2';
$label= 'Districts';
$url= '/honors/district.php';
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/Breadcrumb.php");
$trail = new Breadcrumb();
$trail->add($label, $url, $level);
?>
```

And to print the breadcrumb trail:

```
<div id="breadcrumb"><?php  $trail->output(); ?></div>
```